# rake redmine:plugins:migrate is not executing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, redmine-plugins

`rake redmine:plugins:migrate` is not executing, whenever i try to execute this command, it gives error.

```
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'redmine:plugins:migrate'
```

Answer (score 1):

Redmine has two mainstream versions, 1.x and 2.x.

For 1.x, the following command should be used to migrate all plugins:

```
rake db:migrate_plugins RAILS_ENV=production
```

The command listed on the question was for Redmine 2.x.

Source: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Plugins

Comment: This might answer the OP's question but it would be good if you could expand you post and explain why. Thanks.